# Error insertando fila laravel 5.1 ORM mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

Tengo este codigo en un modelo de laravel:

```
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'We are gonna to save an order with shopify_id: '.$this->shopify_id]);
$this->save();
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'SQL of insert: ', 'sql' => DB::getQueryLog()]);
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'Order saved with shopify_id: '.$this->shopify_id]);
$orderInBD = Order::where('shopify_id', $this->shopify_id)->first();
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'Order in BD with shopify_id: '.$orderInBD->shopify_id, 'order' => $orderInBD]);
```

Y muestra esto en el log:

```
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"We are gonna to save an order with shopify_id: 5074805714"} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"SQL of insert: ","sql":[{"query":"insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","bindings":[5074805714,null,1,"paid","2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00",true,"44.00",44,"7.00",7,"51.00",51,"IT","Via n.34","334 616 6996","60041","AN","Sassoferrato",43.4292,12.8540,"IT","Via n.34","Ancona","AN","334 616 6996","","60041",43.4292,12.8540,"SITEMUERES1660269",null,null,"2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00","2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00","braintree","web",0,"fulfilled","2017-06-22T16:32:35+02:00"],"time":4.6}]} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"Order saved with shopify_id: 5074805714"} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"Order in BD with Shopify_ID: 779838418","order":"[object] (App\\ModelosRelacionales\\Order: {\"id\":252,\"name\":\"SITEMUERES1660269\",\"created_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:32\",\"created_at_day\":\"2017-06-22\",\"paid_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:32\",\"financial_status\":\"paid\",\"accepts_marketing\":\"1\",\"discount_code\":null,\"cancelled_at\":null,\"cancel_reason\":null,\"refunded_at\":null,\"origen\":null,\"referal\":null,\"gateway\":\"braintree\",\"discount_category\":null,\"is_code_applied\":null,\"is_shipping_code_applied\":null,\"is_shipping_native_applied\":null,\"is_compare_at_price_applied\":null,\"subtotal_local\":\"44.00\",\"subtotal_eur\":\"44.00\",\"shipping_local\":\"7.00\",\"shipping_eur\":\"7.00\",\"total_local\":\"51.00\",\"total_eur\":\"51.00\",\"discount_amount_local\":null,\"discount_amount_eur\":null,\"code_discount_amount_local\":null,\"code_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"refunded_amount_local\":null,\"refunded_amount_eur\":null,\"shipping_discount_amount_local\":null,\"shipping_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"compare_at_discount_amount_local\":null,\"compare_at_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"total_real_discount_local\":null,\"total_real_discount_eur\":null,\"shipping_country\":\"IT\",\"shipping_province\":\"Ancona\",\"shipping_province_code\":\"AN\",\"shipping_phone\":\"334\",\"shipping_city\":\"a\",\"shipping_street\":\"a\",\"shipping_zip\":\"60041\",\"shipping_latitude\":\"43.429\",\"shipping_longitude\":\"12.854\",\"billing_province\":\"AN\",\"billing_zip\":\"6004\",\"billing_phone\":\"33\",\"billing_city\":\"\",\"billing_street\":\"Via n.34\",\"billing_country\":\"IT\",\"billing_latitude\":\"43.429\",\"billing_longitude\":\"12.854\",\"customer_id\":\"0\",\"shopify_id\":\"779838418\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:35\",\"fulfillment_status\":\"fulfilled\",\"source_name\":\"web\",\"draft\":\"0\",\"deleted_at\":null,\"user_id\":null,\"user_id_processed_temp\":\"1\"})"}
```

Como se puede ver en el sql del insert, el dato bindeado a shopify_id en el insert into es 5074805714, y cuando nada mas insertarlo hago un select where shopify_id sea 5074805714 me devuelve una fila con shopify_id 779838418. En la base de datos realmente esta con el shopify_id 779838418 osea que falla en el insert seguramente.

Si cojo la consulta y la ejecuto cambiando los ? por lo que corresponde se inserta correctamente asi que me hace sospechar que el problema esta en laravel.

```
insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) values (5074805714, null, 1, "paid", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", true, "24.00", 24, "7.00", 7, "31.00", 31, "es", "Calle", "766", "0311", "a", "busot", 38.4804, -0.4210, "ES", "calle", "a", "a", "6765", "busot", "03111", 38.4804688, -0.4210394, "SITEMUERES1660091", null, null, "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "braintree", "web", 0, "fulfilled", "2017-06-22T16:09:37+02:00")
```

El campo shopify_id es un bigint(20)

EDIT 1
Si uso una consulta raw asi:

```
DB::insert('insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, 
           `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, 
           `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, 
           `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, 
           `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, 
           `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) 
   values ('.$this->shopify_id.', null, 1, "paid", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", true, "24.00", 24, "7.00", 7, "31.00", 31, "es", "Calle", "766", "0311", "a", "busot", 
           38.4804688, -0.4210394, "ES", "calle", "alicante", "a", "6765", "busot", "03111", 38.4804688, -0.4210394, "'.$this->name.'", null, null, "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", 
           "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "braintree", "web", 0, "fulfilled", "2017-06-22T16:09:37+02:00")');
```

Funciona bien.

EDIT 2
Si le resto una cantidad alta al shopify id funciona bien:

```
$this->shopify_id -= 5000000000;
$this->save();
```

Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: Hecho! No me di cuenta de que estaba en el español.

Comment: ¿Pero en la base de datos el valor queda bien almacenado o no? Esa parte no la entendí.

Comment: Usando $this->save() no, Deberia almacenar 5074805714 y almacena 779838418, yo creo que es una conversion o algo que hace laravel de 5074805714 a 779838418 por que al hacer un where usando 5074805714 encuentra la fila con shopify_id 779838418

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos la versión exacta de Laravel, PHP y MySQL que usas?

Comment: Versión de PHP: 5.6.30-1~dotdeb+7.1,
Laravel 5.1 y
Mysql 5.5.49-0+deb7u1